# How do I set permissions / specify which users can interact with "Session 0" on Windows Server 2008R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, services

I'm running a RDS Host and there is some old program with GUI running as a service in [Session 0](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx). And things work quite nicely, just like I want them, for the most part.

As user with administrative privileges, I can interact with the software running in Session 0. Now I'd like to make it possible for some users without administrative privileges to interact with the software in Session 0 as well. Any Windows experts out there know how to do that?

*Just to clarify: I'm not trying to make this software/service interact with the desktop. I'm perfectly happy that it's running completely isolated in Session 0. This question is regarding permissions that allow users to gain access to Session 0. Administrators can do this. I'd only like to know, how/where can one permit non-admin users interaction with Session 0.*

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. I'm not trying to make this software/service interact with the desktop. I'm perfectly happy that it's running completely isolated in Session 0.
This question is regarding permissions that allow users to gain access to Session 0. Administrators can do this. I'd only like to know, how/where can one permit non-admin users interaction with Session 0.